# Maven seems unable to find or copy JAR snapshot - MojoExecutionErrorException

Tags: java, azure, maven, web-deployment, executable-jar

I'm trying to deploy my project to azure and during the very final stage when actually attempting to deploy the JAR snapshot I get a build failure: "No executable jar found in target folder according to resource filter"

The snapshot is actually there directly in the target folder but I cannot figure out why this isn't deploying.

[CLI Response when deploying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9P3F.png)

Comment: could you please open the jar and check if the meta-inf/manifest.mf contains a "Main Class: .." entry?